# Randomly selecting 5 cards without replacement

Tags: probability

Suppose you randomly select **5** cards without replacement from a standard deck of **52** cards. 
In how many ways can you select these **5** cards? In other words, how many samples of size **5** are possible from a population of **52** distinct objects?

I've tried **52!/[(52-5)!5!]**, but cannot get the answer of 25,989,960.

Any help or guidance is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: 52!/(52-5)!/5! = 2,598,960 perhaps there is a typo note: 25,989,960 != 2,598,960

Comment: Thanks for the help! After re-trying it on the calculator I was able to get 2,598,960.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a combination problem so:

$$\binom{n}{k}$$
where $n\geq k\geq 0$ and:

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\,k!}$$

So here, it gives, for $n=52$, $k=5$:

$$\binom{52}{5}=\frac{52!}{47!\,5!} = 2598960$$

Your work is actually correct.